# Passing data from .csv (d3.js) to Chart.js, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: d3.js, chart.js

So I can see that d3.js does it's job and retrieves data from .csv (visible in the browser console)
But I can't pass this data on the chart for some reason, there's no errors in the logs etc.
Thanks in advance! ;)

```
const chartData = 'data/data.csv';
d3.csv(chartData).then(function(datapoints) {
  console.log(datapoints)
  const data1 = [];
  const data2 = [];
  const data3 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < datapoints.lenght; i++) {
    data1.push(datapoints[i].data1)
    data2.push(datapoints[i].data2)
    data3.push(datapoints[i].data3)

    }

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Live data (someday)',
            data: [data1, data2,data3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
                
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `datasets.data` ends up to be an array of arrays but `Chart.js` expects a flat array of values. It's hard to tell without seeing your data but you probably need to define 3 separate `datasets`.

```
const chartData = 'data/data.csv';
d3.csv(chartData).then(function(datapoints) {    
  const myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: datapoints.map((o, i) => i),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Live data 1 (someday)',
            data: datapoints.map(o => o.data1),
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' 
          },
          {
            label: 'Live data 2 (someday)',
            data: datapoints.map(o => o.data2),
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)' 
          },
          {
            label: 'Live data 3 (someday)',
            data: datapoints.map(o => o.data3),
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' 
          }
        ],
        ...
```

Comment: Glad it works for you! In case you think this was the answer that solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2358409).